# Polymorphic Method Return SubClass Type

Tags: scala, oop

Suppose I have a superclass with multiple subclasses. For each of these classes I would like to have an `updatePropertyX` method which updates the property `x` and returns an new instance of that class.

Additionally I would like the superclass to be abstract and I would like to only implement this `updatePropertyX` method once.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
class Super(val name: String, val x: String)
{
    def identify = println("This is a Super with properties" +
        s"\n\tName: ${this.name}\n\tData: ${this.x}")

    def updateX(newX: String): Super = new Super(name, newX)
}

class Sub_1(name: String, x: String) extends Super(name, x)
{
    override def identify = println("This is a Sub_1 with properties" +
            s"\n\tName: ${this.name}\n\tData: ${this.x}")
}

class Sub_2(name: String, x: String) extends Super(name, x)
{
    override def identify = println("This is a Sub_2 with properties" +
            s"\n\tName: ${this.name}\n\tData: ${this.x}")
}

val s1 = new Sub_1("sub1", "original data")
s1.identify

/*
This is a Sub_1 with properties
    Name: sub1
    Data: original data
*/

val s2: Sub_1 = s1.updateX("new data")
```

However there is a type mismatch error on the last line: found `Super`, expected `Sub_1` (also `Super` is not abstract as I would like).

I also tried pulling the method out:

```
def updateSubX[T <: Super](orig: T, newX: String): T = new T(orig.name, newX)
val s2 = updateSubX(s1, "new data")
```

But this is problematic because I don't think you can instantiate a class based on a type parameter (because erasure?).

Any thoughts on how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could use F-bounded polymorphism to return the correct subtype:

```
abstract class Super[A <: Super[A]](val name: String, val x: String) {
    abstract def updateX(newX: String): A
}
```

The type is weird but it does the job.

Now your subclasses look like:

```
class Sub_1(name: String, x: String) extends Super[Sub_1](name, x)
```

Unfortunately without knowing the constructor of the subclass, you cannot actually implement the `updateX` method generically and will have to leave it abstract for subclasses to implement, which is awkward (at least it is enforced though). Since the constructors could take different parameters though, I don't see another (non-reflective) way.

A broader question is: What are you trying to achieve with this? If all your subclasses consist of the same immutable data, what is different?

If it is behaviour only (as in your `identify` method), would dropping inheritance and having only one class with with identify being passed in as a function instead work? Something like:

```
class MyClass(val name: String, val x: String, val identify: () => Unit)
```

That may not be appropriate, depending on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually just found the F-bounded polymorphism just before opening this. What I am actually doing is making a tictactoe-like game where there is a human player and a computer player (base is player, subs are human and computer). The method that will differ is `makeMove` (human waits for input, computer makes algorithmic choice). I might be able to get away passing in the appropriate `makeMove` function

Comment: Here is my F-bounded polymorphism solution http://pastebin.com/zJZTmsSL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.type` as a return type.

```
def updateX(newX: String) : this.type = ...
```

This will return the exact type of whatever inherits the method, up to any other implemented traits.

Comment: Would I then do something like this? `def updateX(newX: String): this.type = new this.type(name, newX)` I am getting the error `class type expected but Super.this.type found`. Also I don't think that would work with `Super` being abstract?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now, that won't work. You do have to overwrite this method in every subclass, same as with triggerNZ's answer. This way is just less wordy.